# Display latest articles inside of a post on wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i was browsing some themes on wordpress, and i found one that is kind of a clone from 9gag.tv

You can see the demo theme here
http://codecanyon.net/item/youtube-viral-videos-9gag-tv-clone/full_screen_preview/6770578

If you see that page, you see the "latest videos" area below, that has the posts arranged by date, but when you open a video, that area changes and it gives you random videos.

Is there a way to arrange the videos like in the home page and allow user to browse to older videos?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but the [Display Posts Shortcode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/) plugin might be the thing you need to get started. You can find documentation [here](https://github.com/billerickson/display-posts-shortcode/wiki)

Comment: @JamesThomas hi there, that's kind of what i'm looking for. But does that plugin allow me to have navigation? Imagine i want to display the 10 latest posts to the user, and give them the power to navigate to the next 10 posts. How would i achive that?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @nCore hi, i haven't tried anything yet. I was looking to buy the theme, but for some reason i think that it's not possible to do what i want in wordpress. Have a look in here :http://9gag.tv/p/K1q7J/the-dworf-of-westeros-the-wolf-of-wall-street-parody-game-of-thrones

Navigate down and click in Next. The page doesn't reload and it gives new videos. That's what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its easy to achieve it using the get_posts() loop. You'll also need to register new custom post_type for whatever posts you're going to post and  fetch it through a loop like the example below.

I'm sure someone else will give a full answer but this will get you started.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'rand' ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        the_attachment_link( $post->ID, false );
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress php function `get_posts()` to fetch the posts, then echo the data you want using a foreach. The function also has the offset argument which you can use for the navigation.

Comment: Hmm and how would i integrate the navigation that is already done @Aister?

In the example gave above, i want to offset it by 10 for example.

Comment: @PedroLino The answer given by nCore below has the link to get_posts() function. In that link there is an instruction to set the offset, as well as every parameters you can use to customize it. Just remember that the function is get_posts, with a plural posts and not `get_post()`